# Windows 7: Scheduling automatic VPN connection with WLAN connection

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

There doesn't seem to be any easy way to tell Windows 7 that a network connection should allways use a VPN connection (like it is in Linux), so I've been playing around a bit with Task Scheduler to do this.

What I need is to automatically connect to a VPN when a WLAN connection is established. Why? Because if I connect to the VPN manually, every time I put the computer to sleep or hibernate it, the VPN is disconnected and I have to connect manually again. Which is easy to forget.

In Task Scheduler, I've created the following:

Triggers:
On an event -> Log: System, Source: Power-Troubleshooter, Event ID: 1
On an event -> Log: System, Source: Kernel-Power, Event ID: 42

(I found the above in a tutorial, and they seem to work.)

Action: rasdial

This works. When running the task manually, it connects to the VPN.

However, the problem is that when logging in after sleep/hibernation, the task is run immediately. Hence, it runs before the WLAN connection is established, thus failing and quitting in a couple of seconds.

So, what I need is to delay the task for a few seconds, until the WLAN connection is established. Either for a specified number of seconds, or better - wait for the WLAN connection to be established.

Is there any way of doing this, without creating a script file with a wait function? The task can be set to retry if it fails, but only with 1 minute intervals, which is much too long.

If the only solution is to create a script file for starting the VPN connection, and adding a wait function there, could someone show me an example? (I'm not good at windows scripting at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do that without scripting it. At least not that I know of (which doesn't necessarily mean very much).

If you want to script it, here's a simple .vbs script that waits before running the rasdial command:

```
WScript.Sleep 5000
Set objShell = "WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run """c:\windows\system32\rasdial.exe"" <vpn connection> <username> <password>", 1, True
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Then just run this script file instead of the rasdial.exe command from the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Looks pretty easy. If there's no simpler way, this will be the solution.